# ViewContainerRef is undefined while accessing inside ng template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

I'm trying to dynamically load components inside, `unsubscribeDisclaimer`.

Below is my `HTML`

```
<ng-template #TooltipInfo>
    <p #unsubscribeDisclaimer></p>
</ng-template>
```

In Component.ts

```
  @ViewChild('unsubscribeDisclaimer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) unsubscribeDisclaimer: ViewContainerRef;

  this.createComponent(unsubscribeDisclaimer, this.unsubscribeDisclaimer);


  createComponent (content, view: ViewContainerRef) {
    console.log(view);
    const componentType = this.contentMappings[content.type];

    if(view) {
      this.componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
      this.componentReference = view.createComponent(this.componentFactory);
      this.componentReference.instance.contentOnCreate(content);
    }
    
  }
```

But for unknown reasons, view is `undefined`

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: at what point in the component lifecycle are you calling `this.createComponent`? access to template views is only available after `ngAfterViewInit`. so if this method is called prior to this hook, it will be undefined. try moving your call to within this hook.

Comment: I tired with both ngOnInit & ngAfterViewInit, even with set timeout

Answer (score 1):

You can take this approach: don't create directive, instead give an Id to `ng-template`

```
<ng-template #dynamicComponent></ng-template>
```

use `@ViewChild` decorator inside your component class

```
@ViewChild('dynamicComponent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) myRef

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    const ref = this.myRef.createComponent(factory);
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Hope you can apply this in your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `static` value to `false` worked.

```
@ViewChild('unsubscribeDisclaimer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) unsubscribeDisclaimer: ViewContainerRef;
```

Comment: according to the angular docs `True to resolve query results before change detection runs, false to resolve after change detection. Defaults to false.` meaning that `true` makes the component available in `ngOnInit` and `false` makes it available in `ngAfterViewInit`. when you changed it to false, were you calling it from `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: @Edward yes you're correct, I'm using setTimeout on ngOnInit method, so it was working, now I moved it to ngAfterviewInit